# What new users see when they wish to learn how to ask questions.

Tags: discussion, design

Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) to see MSE's discussion of how to ask questions, etc. Notice there is no discussion of posting what the OP has tried. Perhaps this page could be rewritten. I would suggest the following:

- A question which most users can understand.
- The OP writes something to the effect that this is what I tried and then I got stuck.
- There is an arrow pointing to the this is what I tried section of the question. The comment for the arrow says something to the effect at if you show what you tried that material someone might be able to incorporate what you know into their answer.
- The first answer does incorporate what the OP knew into the answer. An arrow should point to this.
- A second answer should use an entirely different method of answering the question. An arrow could point out that most problems can be answered in many different ways.
- A third answer might have a "fancy" method of answering the question that is, perhaps, more advanced than the OP might know. A comment associated with an arrow pointing to this answer might point out that sometimes there are fancy methods of solving problems. Any comment like this should avoid the notion that somehow high powered answers are superior.

These are a few suggestions. I am sure they can be improved.

Comment: A related suggestion was brought up by Jayesh Badwaik during the course of the "QA policy discussion" chat, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9214065#9214065).

Comment: I am fairly certain that the /about page cannot be modified like that.

Comment: Someone wrote the code for the about page. My suggestions use nothing that does not appear on the page. Perhaps the powers that be will not change the page but I see no reason to suppose that it can't be done.

Comment: Jay, when I said that it cannot be done, I meant that the about page is a network-wide uniform page, which is more "about sites of the SE network" then it is "about math.SE in particular". I don't know, and I don't think that the StackOverlords have any interest to change that at all. There seem to be an inclination from SE to keep the structure of the sites as uniform as possible, which, if true, means that they won't change it to be a custom page for every site.

Comment: Related: [Should M.SE consider a Question Wizard Guide?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9640/79365) ... [Do we have or should we have a guide for making good questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9612/79365) ... [Could “Ask Question” dialog be more helpful?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8720/79365) ...